# Get certain data from a String

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to read a `string`, (not a file), with the format of `string` `int`:

e.g: `Apples 1 Oranges 4 Bananas 2`

or   `Bananas 5 Pineapple 1`

I'm doing this to calculate the quantity of all items ordered for each customer. I have no idea how to just get the numbers (or even parts) of this `string` though.

```
getQuantity(string order)
{
   while(order.length() > 0)
   { 
     ????
    }
 }
```

Could anyone be so kind to steer me in the right direction?

Comment: `std::istringstream` might come in handy.

Comment: "`Apples`" is not and cannot be a `char`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `std::istringstream` as you would an `istream` object:

```
std::string fruit_record = "Apples 1 Oranges 4 Bananas 2";
std::istringstream fruit_stream(fruit_record);
std::string name;
int value;
while (fruit_stream >> name >> value)
{
  // Process name and value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

psuedo code

```
off =0
loop
  idx = str.find(off, ' ')
  word = str.substr(off, idx - 1)
  off = idx
  idx2 = str.find(off, ' ')
  num = str.substr(off,idx2-1)
```

ie loop through looking for `chars <space> num <space>....`

Comment: This pseudo code really helps, but what happens when there's only one item and one quantity in the string?

Comment: then you only loop once. exit the loop when the search for next space fails